# Force logout after certain time in php

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to logout a user if inactive for 2 minutes (just for testing it's 2min) and when i try to log in the browers throws me to a "redirect loop error". How can i get the user to be logout after a certain time of not being active, that doesn't include closing the page then reopening it though withing 2 seconds as that would be unnecessary to force login again

UPDATE:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['timestamp'])) {
        $elapsed_time = time() - $_SESSION['start_time'];
        if ($elapsed_time >= 60) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `status` = '0' WHERE `user_id` = '$session_user_id'");
            session_destroy();
            header('Location:logout.php');
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['timestamp'] = time();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code you just posted is in index.php then time() - $_SESSION['timestamp'] will always be bigger than 120 hence your loop.
You can change your Session timeout in PHPINI

OR

```
if(isset($_SESSION['timestamp']) {
```

your code here

```
} else {
$_SESSION['timestamp'] = time();
```

this way you will first check if SESSION['timestamp'] has been set

Comment: PHP is server side so it cannot redirect you without user action u need Javascript

Comment: ok i did that, now if i click on anything after i log in, it logs me right out... why?

Comment: U added it where in your old code or new edited one can u place the whole code so we can how and when u call session_start etc, and are you destroying session cookie as well?

Comment: updated the code, i just replaced with what you said

Comment: You have two different $_SESSION ['timestamp'] and [start_time'] thats why

Comment: oh shoot. okay that fixed the problem. it seems like if i close the browser, it will only log me fully out when i go on the website again. is there a way to maintain the time count even if the website is closed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47047/discussion-between-bart-and-bamba)

Answer (score 0):

You need to test for:

```
if($_SESSION['logged_in'] && time() - $_SESSION['timestamp'] > 120) {
    //your code
}
```

Because `time()` - (an unset var) will always be > 120. example: https://eval.in/99143

Edited to add client side javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
    location = 'logout.php'
  },60000)
</script>
```

This will take the browser to "logout.php" after being on the page for 60 seconds.

Comment: Please take a look at the updated code, it seems to work but i have to click on something to see the response of redirect. is there a way to automatically redirect without having to click somewhere on the website first?

Comment: Just use your previous `Location` call instead of `refresh`

Comment: i did that but still i have to click on something before it reacts and redirects

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. Of course this is true. When does PHP do your time comparison? Only when loading a page. If you want it to auto-update after a certain time you need a javascript timer running on the client side.

Comment: oh okay, is there a quick way of doing it? i am assuming it will be something like, if the value is logged out, refresh the page

Comment: Updated answer with client side solution.